# Everything after a loop of unused `new long` runs faster in c++

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management

I am puzzled by this.. This:

```
for (int j=0; j<100; ++j) {
  long* data = new long[0];
}

clock_t launch = clock();
sim.Run();
clock_t done = clock();
```

runs 50% faster than this alone:

```
clock_t launch = clock();
sim.Run();
clock_t done = clock();
```

This is when using -O3. If I use -O0 there is no difference in execution time. Whether it is `long` or `short` doesn't matter. The length of the vector doesn't change anything, either. I am not using `data` anywhere. If I `delete[] data;` in the loop the improvement disappears. As I reduce the number of iterations below `100` the performance gain reduces; above `100` doesn't make any difference.

If this was Java I would think that I am triggering the GC, but this is c++! Also, it is a single-threaded software so it shouldn't be memory sharing optimisation stuff.

What can this be? Does this behaviour be a symptom of bad memory management in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Leaking memory makes code faster? This sounds new to me... :S Seriously, you should post some surroundings and how you are measuring performance.

Comment: Faster than what?  Could you post your entire code and tell us how you are measuring the run time?  What compiler version are you using?

Comment: This code does absolutely nothing. I seriously doubt the way you measure the time it takes to execute.

Comment: First you should post the code that comes after the one you shown. How can we answer your question if we only have the memory allocation part. Moreover, as other said, you should also show us how did you do to get those benchmark.

Comment: Ehi ehi guys! Relax! @MatteoItalia It sounds new to me to, otherwise I wouldn't be posting it here. I can't post a 5000 lines software; after that loop I do a certain type of simulation and measure performance like this `clock_t launch = clock(); simulation.Run(); clock_t done = clock();`. If I remove that loop, the simulation takes 50% longer.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I am using Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I know this code does nearly nothing. I am not measuring how long it takes to run that loop, but the performance of my software AFTER that loop.

Comment: @ForceMagic I would have posted the code if I could have. It is way too long. See the above for the benchmark.

Comment: Does the loop that follows use intensively the heap?

Comment: I use many std:vector, hence I guess yes.

Comment: @enzo: Usually a [simple, self-contained, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org) is required to give a good answer to questions like this one. Find out which of your 5000 lines of code are crucial to the observed behaviour, and which ones aren't. By doing so, you might even find the answer yourself; if not, you make it easier for others to help you. Since you haven't done any of the above, voting for close as "not a real question".

Comment: @DevSolar That simple, self-contained memory-leaking loop is already the result of going through 5000 lines of code. I posted the question because I suspect that some weird c++ behaviour in optimising memory management may be at the root of this problem. The fact that you and the 4 guys above you do not have such a deep understanding of c++ memory allocation, doesn't mean that nobody does. Thanks for trying to help in your own way, but (no offence) you express the typical behaviour of stackoverflow people--when they don't have an answer they blame it on the one asking the question.

Comment: @Enzo: And you (no offense) express the typical behaviour of stackoverflow questioners when told that their question isn't up to standards. I've done C++ work for the last decade, professionally, full-time, including debugging, optimizing, and extending. I've been doing C/C++ development as spare-time hobby for even longer. Like three other people telling you that your question is lacking, I have earned >10k rep answering SO questions. And I *do* tell you, again, like the others, and with confidence, that it's your question (and attitude...) that is lacking, not my knowledge.

Comment: @Enzo: And "self-contained" would mean that I could run that example on my machine and see what you are seeing, a speed increase.

Comment: @DevSolar My question may well be lacking but, given the problem, it is the best I could do. If it is not up to standards then it means that certain questions simply can't be asked on stack overflow. I don't think that a 10k gives you the right to decree which questions are acceptable and which are not. There is really no need to pull down the CV. Even people that builds their whole career on a specific topic don't have the answer to every question. You know, we are humans, you can admit you don't have an answer. Relax.

Comment: @Enzo: You haven't gotten the point. This is not about me not having an answer, it's about you not having a question, which is why this was closed.

Comment: @DevSolar, it was closed because I closed it. Oh no, you actually did. Well done stack overflow. Good job!

Comment: @Enzo: The grey box below says otherwise. Can you please stop trying to look smart?

Comment: If there is someone trying to look smart here that is not me. I have been very humble throughout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you say, "50% longer"? Are we talking minutes, or are we talking seconds?

In the case of a few seconds, it may simply be a synchronization error (two `clock_t` may differ up to two seconds without the real time changing more than a few hundredths of a second).

But my guess is that we're looking at longer times; and without looking at your code, I suspect that by allocating "leaked" memory you "prime" the memory heap, allowing for faster retrieval of information later on.

Which tells me that, yes, probably you're managing your memory less than optimally, and might benefit from pre-allocating and reusing memory ("[object pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)").

With "priming" the memory heap, I mean that memory allocation is usually demanded to a *memory manager* that keeps track of heap memory; using a linked list in the simpler case. Even if you have no *garbage collector*, you still have a *memory manager* which is what lies behind `malloc`, `free`, `realloc` and so on (and `new` also, for that matter). The MM **can** operate by requesting a large chunk to the operating system, and then doling it out to the application, and/or by "tweaking" the requests you make in requests that may be better/faster handled by the OS. For example, the OS usually "sees" memory in *pages* of either 1K, 4K, 64K, depending. If you allocate fifty ten-byte strings on yourself, they might find themselves in different pages and waste lots of memory. The MM on seeing your first request for 10 bytes will maybe allocate 4096, and then parcel them out to you in 10-byte lots.

Now (I'm going out on a limb here!), suppose your application needs to allocate memory equal to a whole page, in ten chunks. Your initial heap allocation, due to the fact that the program itself needs a small overhead, is a quarter page.

So you go ahead and allocate your ten chunks. The first six fit in the partially empty page zero; the next four request a new allocation of a new page, page one.

The allocation done, you start juggling data to and fro your chunks, without ever being aware that they reside in two different pages. Depending on the OS, compiler, optimization and weather forecasts, this might mean that *those operations incur an overhead*.

Now let's suppose that you allocate, and leak, three quarters of a page. Then when you allocate your first chunk, it won't fit in page zero, and the first - and the remaining nine - chunks all go, and fit, in page one. Should -O3 optimization exploit same-page data access, you will experience a **compiler dependent** performance gain.

**Please keep in mind that this is only an ad hoc hypothesis**. It looks plausible to me, but that's not really a guarantee of anything :-)

More details on libc standard memory management (others exist) here

```
http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_3.html#SEC27
```

You might also check out [Google's tools for C++](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am talking few minutes. What do you mean by "prime the memory heap"?

Comment: @Enzo: There is a possibility that you release the memory later on. There is a possibility that released memory is not returned to the OS, but kept by the user-space runtime for later re-use, so that subsequent memory allocations can be satisfied without making another system call (faster). It's a possibility, and it's why people would like to see surrounding code, so we can stop taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: @DevSolar, that was almost poetically put :-)

Comment: @Isemi thanks for your effort.

Comment: @DevSolar I am taking stabs in the dark too, so your ones are well appreciated. As I reiterated several times, I can't publish surrounding code because I wouldn't know where to start and also for licensing issues.

Comment: @Enzo: "Beause I don't know where to start"... in an earlier comment, I gave you a link. That link has a short section, "tricks for trimming". Start from there. By the way, this is a skill, and it is called "debugging".